How to perform a MCU reset after a specific hardfault?
As I didn't find an existing questions on stackoverflow or on google, please find the context below.
I'm investigating an issue leading to 2 different hardfaults on ARM Cortex-M33.
The first one appears almost every time.
The second happens very rarely (only happened a few times during 2 days of intensive testing).
The two hardfaults have different signatures, by which I mean the 1st one is 90% of the time a precise data access error with BFAR valid (so CFSR PRECISERR and CFSR BFARVALID are set to 1, with CFSR value being 0x00008200 consequently).
However, because this 1st hardfault is omnipresent, it is difficult for me to reproduce the 2nd one which I would like to investigate.
Question :
Is there any way to reset by SW the MCU once a hardfault has occured ?
I tried to sort the hardfault signatures based on the CFSR value as shown in the code below, but I was unable to reset the system because the MCU was obviously no longer able to execute instructions.
void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
  /* First hardfault */
  if (SCB->CFSR == 0x00008200)
  {
    APP_DEBUG_SIGNAL_SET(APP_HARD_FAULT);
    
    while(1) {} // Comment this line if NVIC_SystemReset works or there is a way to reset the MCU
//    NVIC_SystemReset(); // Does not work because MCU is in space and cannot execute this anymore
    
  }
  /* The hardfault I'd like to catch */
  else
  {  
    APP_DEBUG_SIGNAL_SET(APP_HARD_FAULT);

    while (1)
    {
    }
  }
}

Thank you for your advices

Ideally you want to find and fix the more frequent fault first. I've never done it on ARM series CPUs but this website  looks to have plausible advice and also the ARM community website has some tips too.

Hello Martin, thanks for the two links, I found the first one but not the last. It's good to know. In fact, both hardfaults have a HW issue as the root cause, however, to delve deeper into the hardware part and reproduce it in simulation we need the simplest possible configuration. Hence SW's efforts to reproduce it, trying to sort through hardfault signatures to obtain signal traces and identify a common pattern within. This work has been done for the 1st hardfault, but I don't know yet if the 2nd hardfault happens with the same exact HW conditions because it's hard to reproduce.

Intermittent low probability marginal timing or noise glitch type hardware faults are very hard to pin down even when you can save the context of each occurrence. I hope you find a way to get a more diagnostics saved in the handler. Good luck!

The normal way to force a MCU reset is to write an invalid sequence to the watchdog register.
For example if you normally refresh the watchdog with WDT.CLEAR = magic_number; then simply write an invalid number instead: WDT.CLEAR = 0;.
As for how to resolve the hard faults, the best way by far is to set a breakpoint in the hardfault handler and when it hits, view the instruction trace in your quality debugger to see which code that was executed just before you landed there.
Note however that some hard faults are caused by things like low-voltage detect or clock monitor, in which case software-anything is screwed and the MCU hardware ought to reset itself. Low-voltage detect peripherals may have a "warning interrupt" though, when the voltage starts slipping but haven't gone haywire just yet.

Side note, for this specific case, using the watchdog required clock readjustments. Thanks for help Lundin, and sorry for the delay to accept your answer (I thought I did but I just upvoted it instead this whole time...)

You can manually reset the stack pointer in the hardfault handler using inline assembly, it's a few lines of code.
I propose resetting stack pointer to the stack pointer startup value, located in the first word of the flash (address 0x08000000). So I would do something of this sort, all of this in asm volatile(""), I will write in pseudo-code:
MOV 0x08000000 into R0, R0 contains the address of the first word of flash
LDR [R0] into R1 load the first word of flash into R1
MRS R1 into MSP loaded that value into stack pointer
At this point, stack should be usable again within hardfault handler, and you should even be able to call other functions from it. You will reuse the memory which was the stack of the original program, but if you don't use too much stack in the hardfault handler, you can even try to inspect the stack of the program when it crashed and possibly learn something from it.

Hello Ilya, unfortunately this would not work as the issue being HW related, the MCU is in space and can hardly fetch and process instructions (to give you an example, before the MCU went outer space, it started executing well the MOV R0, but couln't go further. In addition to that, the stack got some damages). For a SW related hardfault, it might be possible to follow the approach you advised as the fault behavior after the HF could be constant (well, more constant than the "random" I have). In any case, thank you for sharing this approach, I hadn't thought about it

I have an idea: make your hardfault handler a naked function. In that case, the compiler will not generate a function prologue like pushing a frame pointer onto the already corrupted stack (which happens before anything in the function body happens). It could be that everything falls apart before the first statement in the handler, on the function prologue stage. If it helps, then you can actually reset the stack using the method in this solution. I somehow simply forgot about function prologue and that it uses stack before you do. So tell it not to do that.

You mention you're getting a hardfault. But CFSR is reporting a BusFault. Maybe implement all the different fault handlers HardFault_Handler, MemManage_Handler, BusFault_Handler, UsageFault_Handler.
It may be the case when triggering one of the handlers you are actually raising an exception in the Handler itself and it gets escalated to HardFault.
First step would be to figure out which handlers are running. You can set breakpoints on all the fault handlers and wait. Or at the beginning in main, enable the GPIO's you want to use to monitor outputs. In the handlers use 'raw' register access to set a GPIO and monitor them with a logic analyser.
If you see one fault is a busfault and the more transient one is a hardfault:
In one exception handler (busfault) you can force the WDT as others mentioned to reset, or shorten the watchdog reset time and kick it in the idle loop.
In the second fault handler (if they're too separate issues) you can spin and kick the wdt or set a breakpoint.

Hello stevod, all handlers are implemented. They're not triggered due to the hardfaults which have an issue related to clock behavior as root cause
